# maximum recursion depth exceeded with recursive file structure crawl

Tags: python, recursion

Here's my code, the intention of which is to crawl a given folder and look for .md and .pdf files, and build a tree-like structure which describes it.

I'm probably really overthinking it, so I could really use a second set of eyes on this.

```
class Resource_Item:
    def __init__(self, name=None, stub=None, path=None, parent=None, html_file_location=None, documents=[], children=[]):
      self.name = name
      self.stub = stub
      self.path = path
      self.parent = parent
      self.html_file_location = html_file_location
      self.documents = documents
      self.children = children

    def add_child(self, c):
      self.children.append(c)

    def to_json(self):
      o = {
        'name' : self.name,
        'stub' : self.stub,
        'path' : self.path,
        'parent' : self.parent,
        'html_file_location' : self.html_file_location,
        'documents' : self.documents,
        'children' : [c.to_json() for c in self.children] } #len(self.children)
      return json.dumps(o)



def walk_dir(root, parent = None):
  """
  >>> walk_dir("./test_docs/folder containing pdfs/").documents
  ['dummy_pdf 2.pdf', 'dummy_pdf 3.pdf', 'dummy_pdf 4.pdf', 'dummy_pdf.pdf']
  >>> len(walk_dir("./test_docs/folder containing pdfs/").children)
  0
  >>> walk_dir("./test_docs/folder containing markdown and pdfs/").stub is None
  False
  >>> walk_dir("./test_docs/folder containing markdown and pdfs/").children
  ['dummy_pdf 2.pdf', 'dummy_pdf 3.pdf', 'dummy_pdf 4.pdf', 'dummy_pdf.pdf']
  """
  file_or_folder_name_no_ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(root))[0]
  entry = Resource_Item( name=file_or_folder_name_no_ext, parent=parent, path=os.path.abspath(root) )
  for item in os.listdir(root):
    path = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(root), item)

    if os.path.isfile(path):
      if item.endswith(".pdf"):
        entry.documents.append(item)
      elif item.endswith(".md"):
        entry.stub = read_markdown_file_as_html(path)
    elif os.path.isdir(path):
      if dir_contains_pdf(path):
        print('found a path to contain PDFs: "'+str(path)+'"')
        entry.add_child(walk_dir(path))   # broken!
        #entry.add_child(path)
  return entry
```

What appears to be happening is that on the `entry.add_child(walk_dir(path))` line, `walk_dir` doesn't properly create a new instance of `Resource_Item`, since my testing shows that `Resource_Item.children` gets populated with *all* the pdfs in that file tree, not just those in the immediate folder.

As for my supporting functions, I'm pretty sure they work properly, but here they are for completeness:

```
def dir_contains_pdf(root):
  """
  >>> dir_contains_pdf("./test_docs/folder containing pdfs/")
  True
  >>> dir_contains_pdf("./test_docs/folder containing nothing/")
  False
  >>> dir_contains_pdf("./test_docs/folder containing folders, markdown, and pdf/")
  True
  >>> dir_contains_pdf("./test_docs/folder containing markdown and pdfs/")
  True
  """
  root = os.path.abspath(root)
  for item in os.listdir(root):
    item_path = os.path.join(root, item)
    if os.path.isfile(item_path):
      if item.endswith(".pdf"):
        return True
    elif os.path.isdir(item_path):
      if dir_contains_pdf(item_path):
        return True
  return False

def read_markdown_file_as_html(markdown_filename):
  f = open(markdown_filename, 'r')
  markdown_content = f.read()
  return markdown.markdown(markdown_content)
```

---

As another view of how this recursion should be working, I built this other program in the same style to confirm that it works, and it does work properly, so I'm guessing the issue has to do with how I'm using the Python file API:

```
class Item:
  def __init__(self, n=None):
    self.n = n
    self.children = []

  def add_child(self, c):
    self.children.append(c)

  def to_o(self):
    o = { 'n' : self.n, 'children' : [c.to_o() for c in self.children] }
    return o

def bad(count):
  item = Item(n=count)
  print('count : '+str(count))
  if count > 100 or count == 0:
    return item
  elif (count-1) % 2  == 0:  
    print(str(count) + ' is odd')
    item.add_child(bad(count*3))
  elif count % 2  == 0:  
    print(str(count) + ' is even')
    item.add_child(bad(count/2))
  return item


import json
print(json.dumps(bad(7).to_o()))
```

Comment: You shoud do consistent indentation of four spaces, not 2 and 4 mixed.

Comment: sorry... I do keep them consistent in my files, but for posting it here, it got mixed up a bit.

Comment: Please include the full error message; the top and bottom entries in the trace-back are often useful information.  We could also use the trace of the arguments: you should have the canonical print statement at the top of each function -- provide function names and argument values.  I realize that it's not practical to provide a test area for a directory walk.